# GCM Push notification not working on HTC explorer v 2.3.5 in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented GCM push notification in my android application. server side is php. I am getting all push notification messages on most of devices, but I can not get any notification on HTC explorer android version 2.3.5. I have tested other HTC device with version 4.0 as well as other samsung devices and its working fine. Please give me solution for this.

Comment: do you have a SIM in your phone?

Comment: yes. i have SIM and I am using WI-Fi for internet access.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check whether there is google account added on that device.(Settings->Add Account). This account should not be same as the one you used to create the API project in Google API console.
2. In some cases the GCM - SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE will be response while registering the device, so make sure that the device is registered and it got the token the GCM server.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION".equals(action)) {                     
        if (intent.getStringExtra("registration_id")!=null){
            //add log here
        }
        String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");
        if (error!=null){
        //add log here
        }
    }
}
```